# What's the most common way to say "male chauvinist?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Unless "male chauvinist" is the most common way. For example, in Spanish we just say "machista." I'm looking for something short and common, like that. I checked on Google but the only thing I found was that: male chauvinist. The other alternative is sexist. But that's a little different. The word should mean: *the belief that men are superior or more important than women.*

Any other suggestions?

(e.g., For instance, to be used in a sentence like: "Your ideology sounds a bit **male chauvinist** to me).

Comment: Use the word "macho." I implies a male-oriented viewpoint without actually saying sexist or male sexist. It describes a definite manliness. It is an adjective, like in your example.

Comment: @Tear--Here Correct if I'm wrong, but I think "macho" refers to a man who is or pretends be manly "tough." Whereas male chauvinism states that men are superior or more important than women.

Comment: So, janoChen, do you want the word to explicitly convey a belief "that men are superior to or more important than women"? If so, you should probably edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @J.R. OK, done.

Comment: In feminist literature you will also encounter "patriarchal". This refers both to an attitude of male superiority and to a cultural organization which reflects that attitude.

Comment: @janoChen You are right, but that said most people aren't that specific in their speech. It may not be a perfect match, but there's enough overlap in meaning that it could often fit. Plus, it was even suggested in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common way to say "male chauvinist" is in fact **male chauvinist**.

But in your sentence, I would change it into an adjective:

> Your ideology sounds a bit male **chauvinistic** to me.

---

**Addendum** (in response to comment)

It has been suggested in a comment that the word *male* could be omitted. Although the word *chauvinist* is (in my experience) most commonly heard in connection with *male chauvinism*, the meaning of the word is not actually restricted to that usage.

The following are definitions of **chauvinism** / **chauvinist** from three standard dictionaries:

> **chauvinism *noun*** [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=chauvinist&title=21st)
>   *derog* an unreasonable belief, especially if aggressively expressed, in the superiority of one's own nation, sex, etc.
>   **chauvinist *noun, adj.***
>   **chauvinistic *adj.***
>   **chauvinistically *adverb***
>   **ETYMOLOGY**: 19c: named after Nicolas Chauvin, a fanatically patriotic soldier under Napoleon.
>
> **chauvinist** [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chauvinist?q=chauvinist)
>   *noun*
>   a person displaying aggressive or exaggerated patriotism.
>   - a person displaying excessive or prejudiced support for their own cause, group, or sex:
>   - *she wrote off all the local males as hopeless chauvinists*
>   *adjective*
>   relating to or characteristic of a chauvinist:
>   - *a chauvinist rejection of foreign interference*
>
> **chauvinism** [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chauvinist)
>   1 : excessive or blind patriotism — compare **jingoism**
>   2 : undue partiality or attachment to a group or place to which one belongs or has belonged
>   3 : an attitude of superiority toward members of the opposite sex; *also* : behavior expressive of such an attitude
>   — **chauvinist** *noun or adjective*
>   — **chauvinistic** *adjective*
>   — **chauvinistically** *adverb*

It will be noted that the first definition in all three dictionaries relates to *patriotism*, rather than *sexism*. Indeed the word is derived from the name of a fanatically *patriotic* Napoleonic soldier.

Therefore, despite that fact that modern usage of the term seems primarily to relate to *male sexism*, it cannot always be assumed that that is the case. Indeed, there is nothing in the cited definitions to prevent the word being used to refer to *female sexism*.  Having said that, if it is otherwise clear from the context that it is being used in reference, not only to *sexism*, but to *male sexism*, then, of course, the qualifier "male" could be omitted.

Comment: +1 but the compound term "male chauvinist" works fine as an adjective without the -ic. On the other hand *chauvinist* by itself would take the -ic more easily.

Comment: @MετάEd I agree that the noun works OK in *male chauvinist pig*, but somehow, to me, the adjectival form sounds better in *male chauvinistic ideology*, especially when the adjective is separated from the noun as in the quoted sentence.

Comment: You could generally drop the "male" from this example.

Comment: @ChrisH See added **Addendum**

Comment: @TrevorD, thanks - I first wrote the comment a little longer regarding context, but couldn't get it nuanced enough in a standalone comment.

Comment: I finally decided to use *sexism*. I still can't believe English doesn't have a word for this, though.

Answer (score 4):

Consider ***androcentric*** if you are looking for a single-word synonym.

> having or regarding man or the male sex as central or primary

The suggested alternative *misogynist* is not quite an accurate synonym. Whereas *chauvinism* implies belief in superiority or glory, *misogynism* specifically connotes hatred.

[*Androcentrism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androcentrism) on the other hand carries the same connotations as [*chauvinism*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chauvinism?s=t)

Answer (score 4):

Let me argue for a term you mentioned in your question: **sexist**.

ODO defines *sexism* as

> prejudice, stereotyping, or discrimination, typically against women, on the basis of sex:
>   *sexism in language is an offensive reminder of the way the culture sees women*

The term itself is arguably gender neutral, and there can be prejudice and other bad behavior toward men based on their sex.  However, in practice, the term is overwhelmingly used to describe bad behavior toward women.

The term also describes a pattern of behavior that invariably views women as less important, less capable, less worthy and less self-directing than men. Again, there are arguments made that sexist conduct is meant to improve the lot of women (protect them, treat them with deference, etc.), but the views that espouse this are, at best, paternalistic.

*Male chauvinistic* is a pretty good term.  I think *sexist* also fills the bill.

Answer (score 3):

I would think the word 'misogynist' or 'misogynistic' to fit within the example sentence would be appropriate. Chauvinist can apply to nationalistic or racist feelings. Male chauvinist has specific, sexist connotation but in modern usage I feel you could just use the word 'chauvinistic' to convey the same meaning if you need it to be one word.

Comment: Still a male chauvinist is not necessarily a misogynist, not even usually in fact. A male chauvinist believes men to be superior to women which does not imply that he hates them or avoids their company.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a little zinger a while ago:  **retrosexual** (presumably the opposite (?) of a metrosexual).

Comment: If memory doesn't fail me, a metrosexual is a hetersexual man who wears make up and cares "excessively" about his dressing. I have no idea what a retrosexual is.

Comment: I saw retrosexual in a magazine once, sans explanation--Burt Reynolds came to mind.

Comment: @janoChen, retrosexual means "cow boy style". Retro = past

Answer (score -1):

The word you are looking for is [patriarchal](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/patriarchal).

> (e.g., For instance, to be used in a sentence like: "Your ideology sounds a bit male chauvinist to me).

In this sentence, "You ideology sounds a bit patriarchal to me" seems better than "Your ideology sounds a bit male chauvinistic to me", which seems more colloquial.

Also you may want to check grammar rules on use of 'male chauvinist' vs. 'male chauvinistic' in that sentence.

Comment: I don't see how patriarchal (or matriarchal) equates with the belief that one sex is superior to the other.

Comment: OP did clearly ask for other suggestions, also something short and common. Patriarchal seems to fit the bill as a suggestion. It's also listed among options here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvinism. The definition of Chauvinism itself has abridged and varies across dictionaries. The belief of superiority is conflated with enforcing superiority. Actually, action and belief are two different entities and belief is not a prerequisite for action, and so conflating them introduces ambiguity. Thanks for the -1! Chauvinism of chauvinist over patriarchal! :-D

Answer (score -3):

Well, you can try *jingo*; it works for politicians.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that use of the word. Could you please explain why you think it's a good choice? It's probably a good idea to remove the snark too.

Comment: -1 [*Jingo*](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=jingoistic&title=21st) (as in *jingoistic*) refers specifically to *patriotism* - not to sexism, which is what the question relates to.